# V8 C++ API Store Function Pointer?

Tags: api, embed, v8

This question is in regards to the V8 C++ API.

I would like to keep a global reference to a javascript function from a context
That is instead of storing the function in a local handle

```
Local<Function> init = ...
```

I would like to store it in a persistent handle

```
Persistent<Function> init = ...
```

I think the proper way to do so is like so:

```
Local<Function> l_init = ...
Persistent<Function> init =  currentScope.Close(l_init);
```

but **currentScope.Close()** returns a local handle.
Is it possible for me to cache a handle as a class member so i don't have to do a Get every frame?

Can i just have Local as a class variable, assign it using **currentScope.Close** and release it when i'm done with the **Dispose** function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to store it in a Persistent handle you really don't need to worry about scope.  For the purpose of this discussion the major thing the closing of a scope will do is potentially mark your object for garbage collection.

In your example I think you want to do the following:

```
v8::Persistent<v8::Function> init = v8::Persistent<v8::Function>::New(l_init);
```